# How to pack in a certain order with Python

Tags: python, endianness, pack

I would like to pack `0x12345678` into `\x34\x12\x78\x56`

I wrote this

```
>>> a = struct.unpack('cccc', struct.pack('I', 0x12345678))
>>> struct.pack('cccc', [a[i] for i in (1,0,3,2)])
```

But it is very ugly. Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Proper way: using short and reversing the endian type

```
import struct
a = struct.unpack('hh', struct.pack('I', 0x12345678))
struct.pack('>hh', *a)
```

---

*Older answer*
You can reverse the usage ...

```
import struct
a1, a0, a3, a2 = struct.unpack('cccc', struct.pack('I', 0x12345678))
struct.pack('cccc', a0, a1, a2, a3)
```

But it's making a lot of variables

Alternatively, swapping in the array will allow you to pass the result easier:

```
import struct
a = struct.unpack('cccc', struct.pack('I', 0x12345678))
b = sum([[a[i+1], a[i]] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)], [])
struct.pack('cccc', *b)
```

Note: *Their is probably a better way for swapping :)*

Answer (score 1):

One way would be splitting it into shorts and then recombine, though it's almost equally ugly:

```
def pack(x):
    return struct.pack('<hh', x >> 16, x & 0xffff)

>>> pack(0x12345678).encode('hex')
'34127856'
```

To my knowledge there's not out-of-the-box support for mixed endianness in Python.